# How to call app component from router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular5

I am trying to call a method in my `app` component from my loading page say home page. for that in my home component i use:

```
@Output() onPopMessage = new EventEmitter<Event>();

    footerLinkHandler(link){
        this.onPopMessage.emit(link);
        return false;
    }
```

now i need to call the `app` component. since the home page is sitting in the `router-outlet` i tried like this:

```
<div class="wrapper" (onPopMessage) = "onPopMessage()" >
  <header>
    <app-header #dropDownValue></app-header>
  </header>
  <section>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-category-menu [hideDropDownMenu]="dropDownValue.dropDown"></app-category-menu>
    <app-modal-popup></app-modal-popup>
  </section>
  <app-cookie-model (onSetAppCookie) = "setCookies($event)"  ></app-cookie-model>
</div>
```

In my app component my code is:

```
onPopMessage(link){
        console.log('called'); //nothing called
    }
```

so, what is the correct way to call `appcomponent` from any of the page loaded in the `router-outlet`?

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to call a method in my app component from my loading page
>   say home page. Now i need to call the app component. since the home
>   page is sitting in the router-outlet

So, in your homePage component inject `AppComponent` to the constructor and get full access

**HomeComponent**:

```
...
constructor(private appComponent: AppComponent){

}

ngOnInit(){
   this.appComponent.onPopMessage('hello');
}
...
```

[Docs. Find a parent component by injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#find-a-parent-component-by-injection)

Comment: as parallel how to call a method from parent to child?

Comment: as like you said, I am getting the parent component, but the data value changes, the DOM changes not happening.

Comment: @3gwebtrain, What do you mean by `the DOM changes not happening`?

Comment: @3gwebtrain, can you create small stackblitz example?

Comment: it worked for me But I have a question here. Is it good practice to import AppComponent in another component?